# match a particular attribute name = "id" and type ="ID" and comment out this line throughout entire XSD

Tags: xslt

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.28.0">  
  <xsd:complexType name="AccountsReceivableInfo_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="SourceIncomePct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
      <xsd:element ref="DuplicateRecordsPct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="Locationref" type="IDref"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

And i want to match only the attribute name = "id" and comment out the line throughout entire XSD.
I would like to write an XSLT script to convert from above to below and the output should be a XSD.

Resulting an XSD should be like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AccountsReceivableInfo_Type">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="SourceIncomePct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>  
    <xsd:element ref="DuplicateRecordsPct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <!--<xsd:attribute name="id" type="ID"/>-->
  <xsd:attribute name="Locationref" type="IDref"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: [***Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Yes sorry actually the script i was able to write was as mentioned below   without being able to match only the id attribute: <xsl:template match="xsd:attribute"><xsl:comment>
          <xsl:text>&lt;xsd:attribute </xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
               <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
               <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:text>/&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />

Comment: Consider to rewrite your posting to show your question instead of putting the question in a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The task is easy for an experienced specialist, but
somebody new in this area can be "stopped" by lack
of knowledge concerning various details.

So how to do it: The XSLT script must contain such elements:

1. A reference to the namespace used (`xsl`) in `transform` tag, as you will
   use it in a moment.
2. A template matching "your" element in such a way:

   - refer to the particular tag (`attribute`) with the proper namespace (`xsd`),
   - with a predicate `[...]` containing 2 conditions:

     - `name` attribute with value of `id` and
     - `type` attribute with value of `ID`
     - joined with `and`.
3. The content of this template should output a `xsl:comment`.
   Inside it there can be only text nodes, so the content of the comment
   must be assebmled the following way:

   - a space (to separate from `<!--` for readability),
   - `<` char and the name of the current node,
   - a loop for all attributes of the current node, printing its names and
     values (with appropriately positioned: space, `=`, and double quotes),
   - `/>` - to close the element,
   - again a space for readability, before `-->` generated by the `comment`
     instruction.

Note that writing out such chars as `<` or `>` requires that they are given
as corresponding escape sequences (`&lt;` and `&gt;`).

To sum up, the whole script can look e.g. like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="xsd:attribute[@name='id' and @type='ID']">
    <xsl:comment>
      <xsl:text> &lt;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>/&gt; </xsl:text>
    </xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a ton for the script as this worked perfect for my scenario and the script that i managed to write is: <xsl:template match="xsd:attribute">
      <xsl:comment>
          <xsl:text>&lt;xsd:attribute </xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
               <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
               <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:text>/&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:comment>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
    </xsl:template>

Comment: **This is a wrong answer.** You should **never** have to use `disable-output-escaping` to create proper XML markup. To output a comment, use the `xsl:comment ` instruction.

Comment: According to the advice by Michael, I changed "crude and dirty" output with disabled output escaping to `xsl:comment`.